# \includesvg leads to overlapping elements in pdf

Tags: pdf, svg, overlap

I include svg's like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false, width = \columnwidth]{batterie_normal_kw4}
 \caption{Verlauf von Batteriestand, Autarkie und Energieverbrauch bei externer Berufstätigkeit}
 \label{fig:batterie_normal_kw4}
\end{figure}
```

But in the final pdf, some elements are overlapping (see screenshot), which aren't when I open the svg with svg viewers like the chrome browser.

So far I tried out multiple scale settings, but the result is always the same.

Has anyone an Idea why this happens and how I could come around it?

[image: Screenshot of compiled svg in pdf with overlapping elements on the bottom]

Comment: The native \includegraphics is probably more robust. You can convert the SVG to PDF, e.g. via Inkscape or CairoSVG (not tried the latter one myself). Then use \includegraphics to include the PDF instead. Could you try that?

Comment: The command `\includesvg` of package `svg` uses Inkscape to convert an svg file to pdf and uses `\includegraphics` afterwards with the exported pdf. Without the svg graphic in question it is not possible to seek for the cause of your problem. Maybe a solution would be to adapt the svg generation...